# Http Utils, Dotnet Core/Linux

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I have a quick question -- it seems that the responseFilter function doesn't get called under Linux/.net core.

for example:

`"some-valid-url".GetJsonFromUrl(
  requestFilter: req => Console.WriteLine("reqFilter"), 
  responseFilter: rsp => Console.WriteLine("responseFilter"));`

Under .Net core 2.x/Windows 10, both will execute and you will see the output.
Running under Linux, only the requestFilter will print out, and the responseFilter will never run.

Is there something obvious that needs to be done to make responseFilter work? Has anyone else seen this?

I'm on the latest release of dotnet core, and servicestack.

Comment: Looks like the call to responseFilter was removed from the servicestack code 19 days ago... just for the non async version of the function..

Answer (score 1):

This was lost in a refactor but I've just added it back in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/b6966ed3ea2f0d0bbd7ae2e8c0a446ca292fddf6). This change is available from [v5.1.1 on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Which you can get by clearing your local NuGet cache:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

and calling `dotnet restore` to fetch the latest version.